# Usage of "odyssey" and "splendid"

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, word-usage, formality

> I started my **odyssey on** the **splendid** world of mathematics when...

Is this a right way to use the word "odyssey"? Is "odyssey on sth." correct? Can I use "splendid" to describe the world of mathematics here?

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: @tchrist Thank you. I'm sorry it's my first post here and I didn't notice that. I'll pay attention to this rule next time. I might delete this post and ask my questions separately.

Comment: @TomSmith If you'd like, you can edit this post so that it only asks one question, rather than deleting it.  You can still ask the other questions later.

Comment: Off topic (writing advice request). Please visit the [help]. Thanks.

Comment: @snailboat Thanks. I did what you suggested. I'll ask the questions one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are perfectly entitled to describe the world of mathematics as 'splendid' if you want. It is not the word I might choose but then I'm not a mathematician.

I think it would be better to say that you conducted your odyssey 'into'..... An odyssey is a 'journey', a very special journey, but journeys are taken 'into' (or possibly 'onto'- such as a journey onto the planet Mars), or if to a specific destination,  'to'. But by definition an odyssey is a journey which is not to a specific place, so I think your best bet is 'into'.